# How to post to HyperlinkedRelatedField in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-relations

Here I have two models called `PostComment` and `AnswerComment` separately to handle comments in my web application. Now I need to have voting option for both Post and Answer comments. Therefore I though using Django GenericRelations here would be a good idea to continue. I have implemented all the parts and I can't use Django Rest Framework to post data with Django `HyperlinkedRelatedField`. I'm using `rest-framework-generic-relations` ([link](https://github.com/Ian-Foote/rest-framework-generic-relations)) app as DRF documentation has recommended it. It gives me following error when I try to post data.

[image]

Followings are my implementations,

Post and Answer Models,

```
class PostComment(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class AnswerComment(models.Model):

    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment Model,

```
class VoteType(models.TextChoices):
    EMPTY = 'EMPTY'
    LIKE = 'LIKE'
    DISLIKE = 'DISLIKE'

class CommentVote(models.Model):

    voteType = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=VoteType.choices, default=VoteType.EMPTY)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    voted_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Serializer for vote (as implemented in the [documentation](https://github.com/Ian-Foote/rest-framework-generic-relations)),

```
class CommentVoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    voted_object = GenericRelatedField({
        AnswerComment: serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
            queryset=AnswerComment.objects.all(),
            view_name='answercomment-detail'
        ),
        PostComment: serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
            queryset=PostComment.objects.all(),
            view_name='postcomment-detail'
        ),
    })

    class Meta:
        model = CommentVote
        fields = ['voted_object', 'voteType', 'owner']
```

View for vote,

```
class CommentVoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = CommentVote.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentVoteSerializer
```

Urls for vote,

```
router.register(r'comment_vote', CommentVoteViewSet, basename='comment_vote_api')
```

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Try input: http://www.example.com/... (your host server url) like http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: I tried. But it doesn't work either. Gives the same error!